# Merging two columns from two tables in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union, ora-00001

I'm having tremendous difficulty trying to merge two columns from two tables in PL/SQL. I have been working since 9:00am on this and well I give up, please help me.

**Purpose**

I would like to create a new table (call it temp). That merges information from two other columns in two different tables.

**Code So far**

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    (
        temptimeKey           CHAR(24) NOT NULL ,
        temptimeHour          INTEGER NULL ,
        temptimeMinute        INTEGER NULL ,
        temptimeSecond        INTEGER NULL ,
        temptimeMonth         INTEGER NULL ,
        temptimeDay           INTEGER NULL ,
        temptimeYear          INTEGER NULL ,
        temptimeQuarter       INTEGER NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT  XPKTEMPTIME PRIMARY KEY (temptimeKey)
    );

    insert into temp
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q'),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'HH12')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MI')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'SS')), 
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'DD')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'YYYY')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'Q'))
    FROM 
        bus_fare
    UNION
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q'),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'HH12')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MI')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'SS')), 
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'DD')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'YYYY')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'Q'))
    FROM 
        train_fare;

    drop table temp cascade constraints;
```

So far, this code only gives me a violation of unique constraint:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (OPS$FNAVA.XPKTEMPTIME) violated
```

Can you spot what I am doing wrong? (any help is welcome)

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? What does not work? Also, I don't see any PL/SQL here, but so be it.

Comment: try a `GROUP BY TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q'),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'HH12')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MI')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'SS')), 
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'DD')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'YYYY')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'Q'))` at the end of each of your `SELECTS`

Comment: Yes, i noticed late that I did not copy the error. So I edited it and attached it. Please hit F5 :)

Comment: I will give it a try Lamak, hold on a minute :)

Comment: I tried insert it @Lamak n of it but it did not work :(. Thanks though

Comment: Have you tried dropping the PK constraint to see if the insert works? (btw this is not PL/SQL this is Oracle SQL)

Comment: Try it by replacing HH and HH12 with HH24. Maybe you have two dates 12 hours apart causing the problem.

Comment: +1 to what N West says to try, are trainFareDate and busFareDate unique in each of their respective tables?  I don't know if union removes duplicates within a table or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into temp
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS Q'),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'HH12')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MI')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'SS')), 
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'DD')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'YYYY')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'Q'))
FROM (
        SELECT busFareDate 
        FROM bus_fare 
        GROUP BY busFareDate
        UNION
        SELECT trainFareDate 
        FROM train_fare 
        GROUP BY trainFareDate) AS Dates
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS Q'),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'HH12')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MI')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'SS')), 
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'DD')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'YYYY')),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'Q'));
```

Comment: Didn't notice he was using the same column in every column, nice.

Comment: @Overseer10 - Then you must have dates that are miliseconds apart from each other. Updated my answer, so try now and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Lamak - Tried it same issue. Yes, the database is a replication of the Chicago Transport Authority ODBS. So the information can get to miliseconds in detail and I have more than 420k rows on some of the tables.

Comment: TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS Q').  If that doesn't work then TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SSSSS Q').  That takes you right up to your table definition of 24 chars.

Comment: @Overseer10 - Maybe all of this was because we were putting HH: **MM** :SS instead of HH: **MI** :SS. updated answer, try again.

Comment: good catch but no, i took a sample between the hours of 7am and 11am to see if that was the issue but it gave me the same error: unique constraint violation

Comment: I bet you can use your original query now ;-)

Comment: My computer made a sound as if taking off flying. It outputed back: 168724119 rows created

Comment: Nice.  That MM just flowed so nicely for the eyes I never would have noticed.

Comment: @benjynito - yeah, I was scratching my brain as for why it didn't work and then I noticed it...

Answer (score 1):

It's odd, UNION should remove duplicates automatically. Is this on Oracle DBMS?

UNIQUE CONSTRAINT violated errors are due to your query returning multiple rows for the key column on your table that you are inserting into.

In your case, TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q') would be inserted into the key column. If there are two rows with the same MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q, you will get this error, assuming your DBMS is really doing a "UNION ALL".

You could add a second column to your primary key, maybe call it "SOURCE" and populate it with "BUS" or "TRAIN".

Or, you could do a full outer join of the tables.

```
SELECT coalesce(busFareDate, trainFareDate) from
bus_fare FULL OUTER JOIN train_fare ON 
   (bus_fare.busFareDate = train_fare.trainFareDate);
```

Then perform all the work you need to do on the date using that as a subquery.

EDIT:

I think your real problem might be coming from using HH / HH12.

What if you do this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS Q'),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'HH24')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'MI')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'SS')), 
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'MM')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'DD')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'YYYY')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fareDate , 'Q'))
 FROM 
    (SELECT coalesce(busFareDate, trainFareDate) fareDate from
     bus_fare FULL OUTER JOIN train_fare ON 
     (bus_fare.busFareDate = train_fare.trainFareDate));
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that UNION would work like that on Oracle DBMS (which I use). Sadly, adding TRAIN or BUS as a column or as an identifier will cause issues for later purposes. Thanks though :S

Comment: I tried the coalesce early on and tried it now the way you used it with the same results. I ran out of ideas

Comment: I had similar concerns early on regarding that: whether or not HH24 would make it an issue. But the TIMESTAMP by default has it as a HH12 with the end demarcating AM or PM. Besides that I made a test sample of data that only has hours in between 7am and 11am. I tried the insert into in both and the issue remains at the uninque constraint violation

Comment: See Lamak's comments - I bet this was a HH:MM vs HH:MI issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a bus fare and time fare with the same date/time violating the constraint.  Why not try to add a GUID column as the primary key of temp Table and use newid() to generate the value in each side of the union.

Comment: Yes, there are a large number of duplicates between both columns. I figured that UNION would do away with the duplicates but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Also, I need the timeKey to remain as the primary key. Cannot use a GUID (even though it makes it much easier).

Comment: Union doesn't work on just the key column, it works on the entire result set.  If you were working on just one column (the timeKey) it would work as you think.

Comment: So my overall suggestion is to remove the unique constraint, add something else onto the key, or make the select from trainFareDate where TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q') not in (SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q') from bus_fare)

Comment: In his case the entire result set should be the same though, since its all based on that one column.

Comment: I tried a combination of TO_CHAR(trainFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q') not in (SELECT TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Q') from bus_fare) and my computer went berserk, it sounds like its attempting to chug the insert. Brb coffee break.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a TRIM() around your TO_CHAR(), as in:

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR(busFareDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS Q'))
```

I think I remember that TO_CHAR will sometimes add space padding where you might not expect it.  If the space padding causes the total length to exceed 24 characters, then it will be truncated as it goes into the target column in the temp table, which would make it seem that there are duplicates when there aren't (i.e., they are distinct only in the last 2 or 3 characters, which are being cut off).

Alternatively, expand the CHAR(24) column to something larger like CHAR(1000) just to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, some formats will add space padding. But if the length of the resulting string is greater than 24 characters, it will *not* be truncated. It will raise VALUE_ERROR.